# Auto load subcategories content with ajax

Tags: ajax

Recently I posted a question here regarding deploying subcategories contents with AJAX. Thanks to ccprog, it works beautiful fine. However, another question occur after I shared it with my client. They want the first subcategory contents to immediately show on the page, before I click for the next subcategory. To make thing clearer below is the example:

### **Cat A** | Cat B | Cat C

**sub 1** | sub 2 | sub 3

When clicked on Cat A, sub 1 contents should show immediately on the page, before I click on sub 2 / sub 3 (ajax contents)

I did try to work around the codes, however, no luck at all.

Below is the JS code I am using

```
  var links = $(".filter a.ajax");
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

   function cat_ajax_get (event) {
     var catIDText = $(event.target).parent().prop('id');
     var catID = catIDText.substring(4);

     links.removeClass("selected"); // remove class from all lines
     $(event.target).addClass("selected"); // only add it back on the selected

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
        success: function(response) {
            $(".category-post-content").html(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
  links.click(cat_ajax_get);
```

Below is the codes from the page

```
  <?php //Best Practices ?>
    <div class="tabs__content" id="best-practices">
        <nav class="category-group">
            <?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 4));
                ?>
                <ul class="filter">
                    <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
                        <li id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?> ajax" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
                </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="category-post-content"></div>
    </div>
  <?php //End Best Practices ?>
```

Here's the codes in the functions file

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
   $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
   $args = array (
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
   );

   $posts = get_posts( $args );
            global $post;

 ob_start ();

 foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <div class="article">
        <div class="article__thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); 
   ?></div>
        <div class="article__content">
            <div class="article__header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="article__brief"><?php 
     the_field('post_excerpt'); ?></div>
             <div class="article__link"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata();

 $response = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();

 echo $response;
 die(1);
 }
```

Can anyone please show me some direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way... split the AJAX function thusly:

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );

 function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
   $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
   echo load_cat_posts($cat_id);
   die(1);
 }

 function load_cat_posts ($cat_id) {

   $args = array (
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
   );

   $posts = get_posts( $args );
        global $post;

 ob_start ();

 foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <div class="article">
    <div class="article__thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); 
   ?></div>
    <div class="article__content">
        <div class="article__header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="article__brief"><?php 
     the_field('post_excerpt'); ?></div>
         <div class="article__link"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata();

 $response = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();

 return $response;
}
```

And in the template, add a line to get the first subcategory in loop and call the split function directly:

```
<?php //Best Practices ?>
  <div class="tabs__content" id="best-practices">
    <nav class="category-group">
        <?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 4));
            ?>
            <ul class="filter">
                <?php $firstsubcat = ''; // clear just in case 
                    foreach($categories as $cat) { 
                    // to grab the first subcategory
                    if ($firstsubcat == '') {$firstsubcat = $cat->term_id;} ?>
                    <li id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?> ajax" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
            </ul>
    </nav>

    // call the function directly
    <div class="category-post-content"><?php echo load_cat_posts($firstsubcat); ?></div>
  </div>
<?php //End Best Practices ?>
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery to target and fake the click of the correct ID on document load to call the AJAX (replacing '73' with the subcat ID):

```
add_action('wp_footer','subcat_loader');
function subcat_loader() {
    echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('#cat-73').click();});</script>";
}
```

Comment: Hi Majick, thank you for the feedback. However it isn't working. Nothing has been called. The first sub cat contents still empty.

Comment: apart from some debugging to check variables, i'm not quite sure what to suggest here right now... I can't see anything wrong with the code or why it would work with ajax but not directly...

Comment: Perhaps I am really not into coding script at this moment. I will keep tracking and see if I can crack it or not. Thanks majick

Comment: no probs. added a jQuery click example as a simple workaround, but you should be able to get the other code to work by echoing some variables and perhaps seeing what is not being set somewhere.

Comment: When you say echoing some variables. Are you saying what I am thinking? Should I put something here `<?php $firstsubcat = 'some variable here';` and here `if ($firstsubcat == 'some variable here')`?

Comment: could do something like: `if ($firstsubcat == '') {$firstsubcat = $cat->term_id; echo "<!-- ".$firstsubcat." -->";}` and then check the page source.